# Getting all products in shopify that do not contain a tag

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am using bundle builder app that lets users create their own bundles and purchase them. With each purchase it creates a product variation. When there are over 99 variations the app duplicates the bundle product and repeats itself till infinity. The problem here is that the old product bundles are no longer valid but still show in the front end causing confusion. I was able to bug bundle builder app support enough to provide me with info on how to detect these legacy products so we can hide these products from the collections page like so:

```
{%- for product in collection.products -%}
    {%- if product.tags contains 'bundle-builder-dummy-legacy' -%}
        ** do nothing **
    {%- else -%}
        ** print out product **
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Now this hides the legacy products but it still messes up the pagination and the page layout, for example our page limit is set to 8 products, we are on page 2 of 5. Using the above code snippet prints out only the products that do not contain the tag 'bundle-builder-dummy-legacy' (this could be improved with unless statement, but that is not the point), but it leaves empty space - only 6 grid items are filled instead of 8. So I guess the for loop is not working correctly. How can I get the products inside the for loop that do not contain the tag. Meaning an if/unless statement need to happen before the loop or during loop init. Hope I've made clear of the situation I have.

Thanks

Comment: This is clearly as mess created by 3rd party APP builder, in most of the cases 3rd party APP builder create products in the backend but they are not available to the online store, which means their scope is hidden and only used by API, so in this APP is responsible for this mess.

Answer (score 0):

What you might do is asking app to identify those products using a directly accessible attribute of the product, like type.

Then you would be able to do this:

```
{% assign collection_products = collection.products | where:'type','legacy' %}
{% for product in collection_products %}
  Do something 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But this is the opposite of what I want to achieve, no? This will retrieve all products that are legacy, and I want to get all products except legacy ones?